# Pumpkin leaves have weird spots

Tags: pumpkins

I just started doing gardening and I grew some pumpkins from seeds. They were doing fine until I saw some weird spots on the leaves.
[image]

It became worse the second day and the edge of the leaf looked like it was burnt, I was afraid it was some infection so I cut the leaf. Two days later, I spotted the same issue on other leaves from the same plant. I’m worried that this is infectious and would cause it to die eventually.
[image]
I tried to look on the internet but wasn’t successful in finding similar issues (or I’m just super bad at describing and searching for it)

I also noticed weird lines on another pumpkin but I think it’s some leaf miners so I already got pesticide
[image]

It would be great if anyone can help in identifying the issue! Much appreciate!!

P.S. I’m living in California and these days are super hot, could that be an issue?